# Remove image padding in react native ScrollView

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to add an image component to my article scrollView, and using resizeMode="contain" to shrink images to fit the portrait oriented screen. ReactNative is adding a large amount of padding to the image, and I'd like to remove it, but am unsure how.

[Here's a screenshot showing the padding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzVo7.jpg)

Here is my scrollView js code:

```
<View style={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{GetTitle(article.title)}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.author}>
              {GetSource(article.title)}
              {article.author == null ? " - " : " - " + article.author + " - "}
              {article.publishedAt.slice(0, 10)}
            </Text>
            {article.urlToImage != null ? (
              <Image
                style={styles.image}
                source={{ uri: article.urlToImage }}
                resizeMode="contain"
              />
            ) : (
              <View style={styles.buffer}></View>
            )}
            <Text style={styles.content}>{article.content}</Text>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

And relevant styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  author: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  buffer: {
    height: 10,
  },
  caption: {
    fontSize: 10,
    color: "white",
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "black",
  },
  content: {
    fontSize: 14,
    color: "white",
  },
  image: {
    alignContent: "center",
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
  },
  scrollView: {
    backgroundColor: "grey",
  },
  scrollViewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
  },
  title: {
    color: "#fff",
    fontWeight: "500",
    fontSize: 40,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `height: "100%"` from image style.

Comment: Doing this completely removes the image from the page...